# Get wrong screen size (C#/ Winforms)

Tags: c#, screen

I use the following code to get my computer screen size

```
int chieurong = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
int chieudai = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
```

Sadly, the return result is:
chieurong = 1536
chieudai = 864
While my laptop screen size is Full HD (1920 X 1080)
Please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` which represents the actual bounds of the display.

Comment: I tried your way but the result is still (1536X864).

Comment: `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` depends on actual resolution setted in OS display settings.

Comment: It's confusing when the results I run out are completely wrong. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cffRrD8PBdi1IBeJ24F-ZnxGsTHVkX6n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Scaling also does. Set it back to 100% and you'll get 1080p.

Comment: I got it. Since my screen size has zoomed in more than 125%.